# Soundproofing garden

Tags: concrete, walls, insulation

New houses have been built at the back of my house and they are very noisy. 
I want to build an outside wall to get some sort of protection.

I currently have a standard fence panel and a Hawthorn hedge behind it but it makes very little difference.

I live in the UK, in the Cotswold region and these are the stones I am likely to use:

[image: stones]

Will I be more soundproof?

Comment: Unless your wall will be at least 20 feet high I think you'll be disappointed. Refracted and reflected sound will still pass over.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the more jagged and porous the material is the better. In our library, there is porous material put on walls which are faced toward the source of the sound so that it eliminates reflection. Maybe I would try eliminating those reflections between your house and the fence. But given it is in an open space I doubt it will be significant enough.

---

If you are very serious about it, try active noise reduction: [ANC - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control)